# Program to find if a string is a palindrome keeps on failing. Even after using toLowerCase() command for both strings, output doesn't come

Tags: string, palindrome, bluej

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Palindrome_string
{
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("\f");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        int b = a.length();
        String rev = "";
        for (int i = b - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = a.charAt(i);
            rev = rev + c;
        }
        System.out.println("Original word "+a);
        System.out.println("Reversed word "+rev);
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        rev = rev.toLowerCase();
        if (a == rev)
        {
            System.out.println("It is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It is not a palindrome");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The program compiles properly. Still, when running the program, the message which tells if it is a palindrome prints incorrectly. What changes do I make? Here is a picture of the output. Even though the word 'level' (which is a palindrome) has been inputted, it shows that it isn't a palindrome. What changes should I make? [output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MSy7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `==` to compare two strings because it compares the reference of the string, i.e. whether they are the same object or not.
Use `.equals()` instead. It tests for value equality. So in your case:

```
if (a.equals(rev))
{
    System.out.println("It is a palindrome");
}
```

Also try not to use single-letter variable names except for index variables when iterating over a list etc. It's bad practice.